# How much bounty can a question have? Is there any max limit?

Tags: support, bounty

Recently I looked at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544380/improve-geshi-syntax-highlighting-for-t-sql) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) which [rewards the answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) [bountifully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) (> 500).

> [Edit: and for the sake of completeness, I should add [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster/105743#105743) as the
>   current highest reference known to me, having bounty award of `3100`
>   in a
>   *single* shot, awarded by [8 different persons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105743/revisions) - and at the time of this writing has an additional `+50` bounty on going, totaling up
>   to 9 bounties awarded with the expected total of `3150` *so far*. Thanks to
>   [lxrec](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2727470/ixrec). Background for that unbelievably high award is [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/the-number-3-question-has-been-answered-please-share-your-story)
>   and [here](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/10/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster-finally-answered/) (blog), also provided by [lxrec](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2727470/ixrec). The problem takes
>   everyone *1645 days* to answer]

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> "Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned
>   reputation"

And thus, since one person can only slice off maximum of 500 bounty to a question at one time, the bounty must be bestowed multiple times - either by the same person (max 3 times) or by different persons.

My question is: suppose there are 20 users who feel really helped with one answer and each decide to give 500 x 3 bounties = 1,500. Then 1,500 x 20 = 30,000 will be awarded by bounty for that *single* answer.

In short, is this:

[image]

possible?

Is there any limit on how much bounty can be awarded to a single answer?

---

*[Conclusions so far: (1) There is no known limit on how much bounty can be awarded to a single answer. (2) The highest known (expected) bounty up to the time of this edit is `+3,150` - given 9 times by 9 different persons on a [single answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster/105743#105743) ]*

Comment: One more thing is that some answers are incomplete so is it worth giving full Bounty to them or in other scenario 1 questions can have multiple answers so I guess Bounty should be given to all the correct answers and not only to one answer

Comment: @RickFernandes For the incomplete answer scenario, there has been a long discussion about that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button

Comment: There is no known limit, the most popular answer at SO by @Mysticial has received 6 bounties so far.  Good luck getting to 20 :)

Comment: @HansPassant it would have been a lot easier to *give* 20 bounties away than to *get* 20 bounties. :) Could this be the reason why the *giving away* is limited to three per person per answer but *receiving* is unlimited? ;)

Comment: It has a history of abuse to shovel rep to a friend or sock-puppet account that was created when the user was blocked, presumably the reason to limit it.

Comment: @HansPassant Ow, I just knew that painful history... but that makes sense considering how easy a bounty can be given by sock-puppet if it can be done unlimited times..

Comment: In theory, possible. In practice, that won't happen!

Comment: So they finally answer that "monster is the number 3" question? Good show.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No there's no limit.

In practice the maximum reached so far is nowhere near 30,000  though.

At the time I answered [the question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269076/145673) (with DataExplorer data from November) there were 25 answers across the SE network that had been awarded bounties in excess of 1,000 reputation.

Overall the highest was an answer on the Tex site to [How to extract each pair of two adjacent cells of a table into a separate tight page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209821) (+2050). Tex also has another 4 answers with +2000 bounties.

As Ixrec points out in the comments this has since been overtaken by some margin by [Story where the number 3 is the monster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster/105743#105743) on the SciFi site - currently at +3,100.

The highest on StackOverflow is
[Improve GeSHi syntax highlighting for T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773356/73226) (+2000).

Comment: Thanks for the data and the stats. :) I didn't know that there is one `> 2000`. The one which I put in my question is the one which I know has highest bounty reward (2000). But your more complete data definitely show that so far there isn't any answer which receives bounty `> 2050`

Comment: @Ian For the sake of completeness, [this answer on Sci-Fi & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster/105743#105743) has total bounties of +3100 as of this writing, which I've been told is the current network-wide record.

Comment: @Ixrec My God! This is *certainly* an important piece on information! Will add that! :D I am waiting for someone who can point to an answer which has `+30000` bounty!

Comment: @Ian If you're curious why everyone went so nuts over that particular question, [here's the celebratory meta thread from when it got answered](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/the-number-3-question-has-been-answered-please-share-your-story), and the [associated blog post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/10/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster-finally-answered/).

Comment: @Ixrec - Thanks. 105743 was "only" on 1,500 when I did my query.

Comment: @Ixrec and may I know how many people give bounty to that question? Found it. It was 8.

Comment: @Ian [Bounties are included in the revision history](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105743/revisions).

Comment: You say "No there's no limit" but I'm curious how you know this? I'm sure it's true but do you have a reference?

Comment: @DavidG - No there isn't any documentation that there is no limit. In the same way as it isn't documented that there is no limit on the number of answers you can post. The lack of any documented limit is what I based this answer on. I'm sure if it was incorrect an SE employee or moderator would have corrected it by now.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not disagreeing with you at all, just suggesting that comment implies a guarantee where there is none (yet) :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is a limit on how much reputation can be bountied from a question, nor on how much can be awarded to an answer. That kind of thing would be documented in the help center for bounties.

That said, I'd be interested in being proven wrong.

Comment: If someone is extremely interested in testing this... my answers are always available :)

Comment: I like your comment ;) and my answers are most definitely available too! But back to the topic, I realize that there are some hidden rules in bounty which are not in the Help Centre. For instance, one person can only put up bounty by maximum of 3 times to the same answer. This info is nowhere to be found in Help Centre. I know it not from the Help Centre, because of that legendary +2000 bounty case. :)

Comment: One more thing is that some answers are incomplete so is it worth giving full Bounty to them or in other scenario 1 questions can have multiple answers so I guess Bounty should be given to all the correct answers and not only to one answer

Comment: Great, now we just have to convince Jon Skeet to award a +1,000,000 bounty on a question when he reaches it:-)