# Can I award another bounty to an answer already got a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

Let's say there is a question called Q and it already has answered.One of the best answers (Answer A) already got a bounty(+50).

1. I gave that bounty to (Answer A) now can I award another one to the same answer again ? means answer A will get (+50) + (+100) = (+150) , at the end will it display as the (Answer A) gets (+150) bounty?
2. Someone else already given that bounty/not me for (Answer A).Like I mentioned can I send another one for the same answer? (+50) + (+50)
3. Agree with @DavidG's comment and got another doubt, in that case can other users see that how many bounties are in total received for an answer like my (Answer A). Example will be like I can send a (+100) only once or (+50) x 2 times so anyway it will end in (+100) regardless of the number of bounties.Can we see the total number of bounties on that (Answer A) or just the points? Of course we can see the names of the people who gave bounties but what if they are from a single person?

Seems this is possible yet asking before reword a one to clear things.

Comment: It's certainly possible for an answer to get multiple bounties ([for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544380/improve-geshi-syntax-highlighting-for-t-sql/23773356#23773356)), though I doubt one user could do it multiple times (seems like an easy cheat to gift a person a lot of rep)

Comment: @Paul Crovella i see, so if we do it multiple times name will repeat thats good and nice example from DavidG. In that example seems that user gave 3 times :)

Comment: The indicators beside the answer will be consolidated (a single +100, not +50 and another +50), but the details of who gave what bounties to whom are visible in the question's revision list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanking to @DavidG's comment I can see

[image]

Here in the [above scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773356/5188159) OP has asked the question and given bounties 3 times for the answer!

1. Yes, I can reword bounties again an again (seems there is no limit for that with the question here [How much bounty can a question have? Is there any max limit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315517/how-much-bounty-can-a-question-have-is-there-any-max-limit)) to an answer.
2. Yes we can send another bounty to an answer which already has a bounty/ies form others
3. When we hover on the bounty we can see the names of the people who gave the bounty and if a person gave more than one from the order users placed bounties there names are mentioned.

<sub>And finally my question seems kind of a duplicate with [How much bounty can a question have? Is there any max limit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315517/how-much-bounty-can-a-question-have-is-there-any-max-limit)</sub>